# How to get at authorization cookie programmatically?

Tags: java, rest, cookies

I have to implement an upload of a document to an archiving system via REST-interface using Java with spring boot.

I was told to make a GET request with Basic Authentication first. This will give me the authorization-cookies in the response. Then I have to send these cookies with the POST-request to do the actual archiving.

The GET works fine.
I read on the internet that I should get cookies in the "Set-Cookie" - header of the response.
But I get no cookies.

The strange thing is that if I execute the request with Postman, I get 2 cookies ("AuthSessionId" and "ClientId"). 
Why don't I get these programmatically?

As a sidenote: Postman also shows that I got 15 (other?) headers in the response. I have no problems finding these in my ClientHttpResponse

Here is some code:

```
ClientHttpResponse response = request.execute();
    // this is  org.springframework.http.client.ClientHttpResponse

List<String> cookies =  response.getHeaders().get(HttpHeaders.SET_COOKIE);

if (cookies != null) {
    for (String cook : cookies) {
         System.out.println("cookie: " + cook);
    }
} else {
    System.out.println("no cookie in " + HttpHeaders.SET_COOKIE); // this is what I get
}
```

Comment: How do you build the request factory? For example, if you're using Apache's HttpClient implementation, it intercepts cookies headers and removes them, keeping them in a cookies store instead, which Spring's http interfaces don't expose. In that case you'd be better off using Apache HttpClient classes themselves and reading up on how to access cookies doing that.

Answer (score 0):

kumesana is right. The cookies are filtered out and put into a CookieStore. If I set this before, I can fetch them after the request is finished:

```
CookieStore cookieStore = new BasicCookieStore();
CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder
            .create()
            .setDefaultCredentialsProvider(credentialsProvider)  
            .setConnectionManager(poolingConnectionManager)    
            .setDefaultCookieStore(cookieStore)
            .build();
```